# How to split string such that it contains less than n characters with a twist

Tags: python, split

I have a long string which I want to save to a file. Words are separated by spaces. It is given that the number of words in long string is divisible by 3.

Basically I'm looking for a way to split string into chunks. Each chunk is less than n characters and the number of words in a chunk is also divisible by 3.

e.g.

```
>>> longstring = "This is a very long string and the sum of words is divisible by three"
>>> len(longstring.split())
>>> 15
```

say max line length is n=30:

```
>>>split_string(longstring, 30)
['This is a very long string', 'and the sum of words is', 'divisible by three']
```

In summary, the rules are:

1. No line longer than n characters.
2. A twist is that each new line must contain multiple of 3 words.

So far I tried using textwrap but I don't know how to implement 2.

```
import textwrap    
textwrap.fill(long_line, width=69)
```

Comment: The total number of words in a string is divisible by 3.

Comment: I'd split your string into words, then for each word, test if it would make the current sentence too long.  If so, freeze the current sentence and use the the word as the start of the next line.

Answer (score 1):

If you are certain that the total number of words in a string will always be divisible by 3, you can do something like this:

```
import sys
#long string; 84 words; divisible by 3
longString = "The charges are still sealed under orders from a federal judge. Plans were prepared Friday for anyone charged to be into custody as soon as Monday, the sources said. It is unclear what the charges are. A spokesman for the special counsel's office declined to comment. The White House also had no comment, a senior administration official said Saturday morning. A spokesman for the special counsel's office declined to comment. The White House also had no comment, a senior administration official said Saturday morning."
#convert string to list
listOfWords = longString.split()
#list to contain lines
lines = []
#make sure number of words is divisible by 3
if  len(listOfWords) % 3 != 0:
    #exit
    print "words number is not divisible by 3"
    sys.exit()
#keep going until list is empty
while listOfWords:

    i = 0
    line = ""
    #loop for every line
    while True:
        #puts the next 3 words into a string
        temp = " ".join(listOfWords[i:i+3])
        #check new length of line after adding the new 3 words, if it is still less than 70, add the words, otherwise break out of the loop
        if len(line) + len(temp) > 70:
            break
        line += "{} ".format(temp)
        i+=3
    #remove finished words from the list completely
    listOfWords = listOfWords[i:]
    #adds line into result list
    lines.append(line.strip())

#to make sure this works
for line in lines:
    print len(str(line))
    print "Number of words: {}".format(len(line.split()))
    print "number of chars: {}".format(len(line))
    print line
    print "----------------------------------------"
```